# Are there analogs of smooth partitions of unity and good open covers for PL-manifolds?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, manifolds, partition-of-unity, pl-manifolds

Smooth partitions of unity and differentiable good open covers are important technical tools in the realm of smooth manifolds.

Are there analogs of these tools for piecewise linear manifolds?

A *PL good open cover* of a PL-manifold is a locally finite open cover {U<sub>i</sub>} such that every finite intersection of U<sub>i</sub> is either empty or PL-isomorphic to R<sup>n</sup>.

A *PL partition of unity* subordinate to an open cover {U<sub>i</sub>} of a PL-manifold X
is a family of nonnegative PL-functions f<sub>i</sub>: X→R such that supp f<sub>i</sub> is a subset of U<sub>i</sub>, supp f<sub>i</sub> form a locally finite family, and the sum of f<sub>i</sub> is 1.

**Do PL-manifolds admit PL good open covers?  Do open covers of PL-manifolds admit subordinate PL partitions of unity?**

Comment: Stupid question - to find a good open cover can I just: fix a triangulation, barycentrically subdivide a few times, and then take the stars of top-dimensional simplices?

Comment: Yes, certainly they have PL partitions of unity.  For smooth manifolds all you need for the proof is small bump functions, which have nice piecewise-analytic explicit formulas.   On a PL manifold you can manufacture your bump functions much more easily -- take a suitably-refined triangulation, force the function to be 1 on a top simplex, 0 away from a small neighbourhood and linearly interpolate the rest.  The remainder of the proof is just like the smooth category.

Comment: It seems to me like PL partitions of unity would be less useful though, as you rarely have useful vector bundles to work with.

Comment: @SamNead: Is it obvious that all finite nonempty intersections are isomorphic to R^n in your construction?

Comment: I think that all intersections are again open stars (union of open simplices whose closures contain a given simplex).  Thus the axioms of a PL manifold should take care of me.  (A star is the open cone on a link, and all links are PL spheres of the correct dimension.)  I'm by no means an expert...